# How to make android studio do automatic casting?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a way to make android studio perform automatic type casting for objects without the need to do that manually?

Comment: I want to say no, but an example of what you are taking about would be nice.

Comment: Casting is not the thing you want to do often. If you do it often then there's, probably, something wrong with your code. Could you show why you need that?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a way to do this automatically and IMHO this would be not that useful. There might be some cases where you don't want a cast (or a cast different to the one Android Studio suggests). If it would be done automatically you might not notice it it could lead to strange (i.e. unexpected) behaviour which is quite difficult to detect later.

What Android Studio can do for you: It can give you a warning and suggest a cast. For example, when you do a `findViewById()` call and want to assign the result to a View object you do something like this:

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Android Studio will highlight the line because you need to cast the returned `View` object to a `Button`.
By moving the cursor to the line and pressing `Alt`+`Enter` you can select the option "Add cast.." and it will insert the cast for you:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```